# Proxy and Reverse Proxy on same server

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy

I want to setup a proxy server to handle web filtering on our company network. I also want to use a reverse proxy to enhance the security of our web server.

Is is possible to run both on the same server? If it is possible, is it a bad idea?

Comment: What OS and proxy server software are you using?

Comment: We are using Windows 2003. We haven't decided on a proxy server yet, but are thinking along the lines of either IAS or Squid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of products that can act both as proxy and reverse proxy. In the Microsoft world, ISA Server is great for both roles. There are no special issues in doing both things at the same time on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

Squid will certainly do what you propose to do without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

They will be running on different ports, so you can definitely run both services on the same machine without troubles.